# Neo4j weights on node labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a requirement where I want to add weights to the node labels and return the queried list based on these weights. Suppose a person node has two labels company and title and a search query matches both these fields, since the company label has more weight assigned, it should be returned on top of the list. I have created FULLTEXT index on node labels for search already.

Is it possible to do something like this with neo4j ?

Comment: Are you putting `Person`, `Company`, and `Title` labels on the same node? If so, you probably need to rethink your data model. Can you fill in your question with details of your use case and data model; and show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene query language also supports boosting the score of the results with the caret (^) operator. Suppose you add a string property called `weight` to all your nodes.

Create a sample dataset:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:"Joan" , weight:"1"}),
       (:Company {name:"Joan" , weight:"2"}),
       (:Movie {name:"Joan" , weight:"3"})
```

Now create a full text index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX example IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:Person|Company|Movie)
ON EACH [n.name, n.weight]
```

Finally, you can query the index and provide custom boosting options:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("example", "name:Joan weight:1^1 weight:2^2 weight:3^3") 
YIELD node, score
RETURN node.name, labels(node)[0] AS label, score
```

Results:

Table
Text
Code

```
╒═══════════╤═════════╤══════════════════╕
│"node.name"│"label"  │"score"           │
╞═══════════╪═════════╪══════════════════╡
│"Joan"     │"Movie"  │1.3981904983520508│
├───────────┼─────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Joan"     │"Company"│0.9523590207099915│
├───────────┼─────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Joan"     │"Person" │0.5065275430679321│
└───────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┘
```

You can see how movie comes up with the highest score as it has the largest weight. And yes, you probably need to include the weight for every node, I don't know how to do something generic on node label level, except if you customize the lucene index yourself. Learn more about that in: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/full-text-analyzer-provider/